# Вся правда о символах

Tags: ruby

В одном из тестов наткнулся на такой вопрос:

> Что из нижеследующего, сказанного о символах (symbols), является
>   истиной?
>
> Выберите один или несколько вариантов:
>
> a. Несколько копий символа могут существовать одновременно
>
> b. Только одна копия любого символа может существовать в единицу
>   времени. Таким образом экономится память.
>
> c. Символы -- неизменяемые объекты, т.е. они не может быть изменёны
>   после создания.
>
> d. Символы-ключи быстрее строк-ключей

Согласно [документации](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html):

> Symbol objects represent names and some strings inside the Ruby
>   interpreter. They are generated using the :name and :"string" literals
>   syntax, and by the various to_sym methods. The same Symbol object will
>   be created for a given name or string for the duration of a program's
>   execution, regardless of the context or meaning of that name. Thus if
>   Fred is a constant in one context, a method in another, and a class in
>   a third, the Symbol :Fred will be the same object in all three
>   contexts.
>
> ```
> module One
>   class Fred
>   end
>   $f1 = :Fred
> end
> module Two
>   Fred = 1
>   $f2 = :Fred
> end
> def Fred()
> end
> $f3 = :Fred
> $f1.object_id   #=> 2514190
> $f2.object_id   #=> 2514190
> $f3.object_id   #=> 2514190
> ```

Т.е. символ всегда существует лишь в одной копии, и из набора ответов `[a, b]`, правильным является ответ `b`. Поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.

А вот что насчёт `[c, d]`?  Правильно ли я понимаю, что из `b` вытекает и `c`? Я бы хотел увидеть развёрнутый ответ на эту тему с ссылкой на документацию. И верно ли утверждение, что символы-ключи в хеше работают быстрее?

От себя ещё хотел бы добавить ещё один вопрос: я привык использовать symbol в качестве ключа в hash. Но какое ещё применение им можно найти (в рамках Ruby-way, конечно)? Не исключено, что именно из непонимания предназначения символов вытекают все мои глупые вопросы.

Comment: Как по мне, верно b,c,d. В руби строки изменяемые, поэтому есть символы для оптимизации. И по идее они быстрее, ведь они не требуют явного сравнения строк в силу своей неизменности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Прежде чем начать, напомню, что в Ruby держаться за объекты можно **только по ссылке**.*

---

**Символы** суть **интернированные строки**.
Ну, почти. На самом деле это **уникальные идентфикаторы** интернированных строк.

То есть, где-то в интерпретаторе есть глобальный мап `{ название<PrivateString> => символ }`. **Значение символа само по себе не несёт никакого смысла**, но поддаётся сравнению (причём, *быстрому*) на равенство и содержит ссылку на своё `название`.

`PrivateString` это абстрактная деталь реализации: нечто очень похожее на строку и имеющее возможность сравнения со `String`, но **недоступное из Ruby**.

Когда интерпретатору нужно получить символ с определённым названием (по явному указанию в программе или при встрече литерала символа), он смотрит в глобальный мап и либо берёт символ, который там есть (если это же название туда ранее было помещено), либо вставляет запрашиваемое `название` в этот мап, создаёт новый `символ` и возвращает его.

Таким образом, названия и символы находятся в отношении 1-к-1. Таким образом:

> Только одна копия любого символа может существовать в единицу времени.

**Можно ли изменять символы?..** После прочтения вышеизложенного должен возникнуть закономерный вопрос: "А что там менять-то?" Символ определяется своим `object_id` и указателем на `PrivateString` с его названием. И значение `PrivateString` получить невозможно. Так что:

> Символы -- неизменяемые объекты, т.е. они не могут быть изменёны после создания.

Осталось последнее. **Быстрее ли они в качестве ключей, чем строки?** (Предполагаю, что речь о ключах в `Hash`) *Принято считать, что да.* Но что кто-то там считает неинтересно, верно?

Берём лопату и идём смотреть асимптотику.

- Символы сравниваются за `О(1)`, по `object_id`, но при условии, что оба символа встречаются не впервые: в противном случае их надо будет сначала поместить в глобальный мап. Один раз за время их жизни.

  - Время жизни это отдельная тема. В Ruby 2.2 символы, наконец, начали собираться сборщиком мусора! До этого символ, появившись в программе один раз, существовал до самого завершения. Поэтому делать символы с названиями из пользовательского ввода было опасно. Невинный `params[:foo].to_sym` мог случайно устроить вам Denial of Service.
- Наивное сравнение строк `O(N.size)`. Но если использовать хэширование, ситуация усложняется. Хэши сравниваются за `O(1)`, т. к. имеют фиксированную длину.

  - Брать хэши всё равно придётся за `O(N.size)`, но их можно сохранять, они останутся актуальными до очередного изменения строки.
  - **Равенство хэшей значений не гарантирует равенство значений (коллизии!).**

    - Но *для заранее известных строк* можно подготовить **идеальную хэш-функцию**, коллизии в которой отсутствуют. Используется ли это в Ruby, я не знаю, но учитывая мутабельность строк в Ruby, это было бы нерационально. В MRI используется библиотека `gperf`, но для этого ли, я не в курсе. Предполагаю, что она используется для мапа символов, но не ручаюсь.
  - Когда объект сравнивается с самим собой... `O(1)`.
  - В сухом остатке, строки придётся сравнивать в худшем случае за `O(N.size)`.

Уф. Так что быстрее? Смотря в какой ситуации.

Если множество ключей невелико (или редко меняется), символы прекрасно справятся: они будут быстренько добавлены в общий мап и далее все операции с ними будут молниеносными. И обычно множество ключей действительно известно заранее и невелико.

Если множество ключей потенциально велико (пользовательский ввод), то ситуация усложнятся (опять). Время добавления в глобальный мап всё-таки не нулевое, но если оперировать с обычными строками, любой выигрыш во времени устранится уже за несколько операций.

Поэтому...

> Символы-ключи быстрее строк-ключей

...как правило. В каких-то искусственных условиях, вероятно, они могут вести себя медленнее, но на практике такие случаи малореальны.

---

**Обновление:** начиная с MRI 2.3 появился режим frozen string literals, который *литералы* строк в исходном коде воспринимает как замороженные, а потому неизменяемые, а потому к ним можно применить те же оптимизации, что и к символам.